# undefined identifier, eval expression in file

Tags: scheme, eval, racket

How do I set things up so that I can call `eval` on quoted forms of procedures defined in the same file as they are evaluated?

minimal example. I have the three expressions written into a file.

```
#lang racket

(define (foo x) x)

(define bar (eval '(foo 1)))
```

When I load the file I get the following.

```
eval-tests.rkt﻿> 
; foo: undefined;
;  cannot reference undefined identifier
; Context:
;  /Users/.../code/gen-scheme/lib/eval-tests.rkt:1:1 [running body]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the [racket guide on eval](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/eval.html)

```
#lang racket

(define-namespace-anchor a)
(define ns (namespace-anchor->namespace a))

(define (foo x) x)

(define bar (eval '(foo 1) ns))
```

Comment: When you're done with that, read Matthew Flatt's excellent note on eval: [on eval in dynamic languages generally](http://blog.racket-lang.org/2011/10/on-eval-in-dynamic-languages-generally.html)